# Asterisk in Access dataset causing error

Tags: database, ms-access, escaping, asterisk

I've never really done anything with Access before (though I have done a lot with MySQL and PHP), so this is sort of my first go. It's simple enough: two tables, tblShapes and tblExamples. They are linked by "JCH Shape" which is primary in tblShapes (it's text). I made a form with a combobox that can select a JCH Shape. I then requery the form so that a subform can be populated with the appropriate data.

Some of my data, though, is differentiated only by asterisks. So, right now, the values for the column JCH Shape in the rows I have are:

- (g)CVC
- (g)C*V
- CV*CV
- CVCV

I was fine until I added that last value, "CVCV". Now, whenever I click it, any time I try to select other data, the form requeries, but displays blank data until I close the form and reopen it, unless I select CVCV, in which case it displays its own data just fine, as if the form thinks everything else has lost its associated data.

Asterisk is definitely the problem here, but it only is a problem when it distinguishes CV*CV and CVCV, or other forms where the only distinguishing character is * (it doesn't affect (g)CVC and (g)C*V, for example, but when I tried making (g)CV, the same problem occurred). I don't understand. I'm figuring something is going wrong when I call Requery, but I don't know enough about how Access works internally to know if it falsely interpretting * as a wildcard, or if I'm doing something wrong.

I've linked to the file. I know it's messy, but it's my first attempt. Any help would be very much appreciated:

http://the-polyglot.net/uploads/other/SP-JCH-Words.accdb

Thanks!

EDIT: Now in the version I uploaded, it appears to be doing it for every entry after the first one clicked. I don't understand at all. It was only doing it when I clicked CVCV 5 minutes ago and the only thing I did was closed and reopened Access.

Comment: Asterix is the wildcard character in `MS Access`, not the usual % you may find with `MySQL` and others, if you could post the SQL statement which populates your forms we can take a closer look, however I suspect the way to do it is to wrap in double quotes e.g. **""CV*CV""** this will then treat it as a string value and not apply the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had the same thought process, but I think the query that is causing the problem is implicit: I don't actually have any SQL anywhere in the code. I think the problem is coming from Access' own implicit querying when I try to populate the form.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be using an Autonumber primary key for the tblShapes table, so that each 'Shape' has a unique value. There should be a foreign key value in tblExamples to show the relationship between the tables.

Secondly, (regardless of whether you follow my first point), you have a main form and two subforms.

The main form should have the RecordSource set to nothing.

The LinkMaster properties of the subforms should be set to the name of the combobox.

I would give the controls names with preceding three letters such as cmb for combobox and txt for textbox. This will make the code clearer and avoid conflicts where fields and controls are suing the same name.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I decided to use the text field as the primary key because each must be unique anyway (and it was messing up the drop box). I tried following your advice and setting the RecordSource to nothing and setting the Master Link to the combobox, but then Access complains that I cannot make a link between unbound forms. Any ideas?

Comment: Only the master form should be unbound. The subforms should be bound. The ChildLink property must be the name of a field, but the MasterLink property can also be the name of an unbound control. Check that your control names are not conflicting with field names.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I was using a criterion on the main form's recordset `Like [Forms]![Add Record]![ShapeCombo]`

So, this derived to `Like CV*CV`  in some cases. I changed this to just a literal match and it works fine. I still wonder if there's an easy way to escape sensitize characters in Like expressions, though. Does anyone know of a way other than doing a manual string replace and changing `*` to `[*]`, for example? My problem is fixed, but I'm just curious how I would solve it if I were to need to use a Like expression with both intended wildcards and literal asterisks.